# when calling function modifies the pointer how to free the memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, free

I need to write a function that has an array as its input, and needs to move the head of array at each function call, to show my problem simply, I designed the following simple example:

```
void testFunc(FLOAT* &testVec)
{
   std::cout << " testVec " << *testVec << "\n";
   ++testVec;

}
```

in the `main()` I have:

```
FLOAT** testVec;
testVec = new FLOAT*[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
testVec[i] = new FLOAT[3];

testVec[0][0] = 1.0;  testVec[0][1] = 2.0;  testVec[0][2] = 3.0;
testVec[1][0] = 4.0;  testVec[1][1] = 5.0;  testVec[1][2] = 6.0;

for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
     testFunc(testVec[i]);

  }

}
```

this piece of code works well and prints the values from 1.0 to 6.0 as I expect, However, I do not know how to delete `testVec` after this, since the function is changing `testVec[i]`. Is there any way to free memory in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question as asked, is that you need to save a copy of the result of `new`, and delete that:

```
FLOAT** testVec = new FLOAT*[2];
FLOAT** savedVec = testVec;
....
for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    delete [] savedVec[i];
delete [] savedVec;
```

---

However, this is making life very, very, hard for yourself.  In C++, you almost always want to use `std::vector` or `std::array` rather than new and delete.  You could probably use:

```
std::vector<std::array<FLOAT,3>> testVec(2);     // A two element vector of
                                                 // three element arrays.
```

or

```
std::vector<std::vector<FLOAT>> testVec(2);      // A two element vector
                                                 // of vectors:
for (auto &element : testVec) element.resize(3); // Resize each element
```

Your declaration and implementation of `testFUNC` would then need to change too.

---

Final comment:  You need to reset `testVec` each time round the for loop from 0 to 3 too.  Otherwise, the second time round the loop it is pointing off the end of the array.